# How to implement Android google maps coordinates picker like in Telegram

Tags: android, google-maps, picker

I want to implement coordinates picker like in Telegram, when map is draggable but marker stays in the static center position. How to achive this with Google Maps api for Android.
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this problem?